# Working with new AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I've recently started working with AndEngine. I went through online tutorials, video lectures, bought a book by Rick Rogers but the basic problem with AndEngine is that all its study material is out-dated and the new version has most of the packages changed.

I tried to execute AndEngine examples but since they are built using previous version of AndEngine they don't work with new libraries. I'm very confused how should start learning new AndEngine since I can't find any tutorials or examples!

It would be really helpful if you could provide me with a link to a previous version of AndEngine so that I could atleast implement older examples. Any better alternative to AndEngine would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently started working on latest AndEngine, and I am developing a 2d game. [Here](https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/jimvaders-my-own-invaders-clone-thingie-tutorial/) is very nice tutorial and it's using latest AndEngine code to get you started :).

In my point of view **AndEngine is best for Android 2dGame development.** Other good option is Cocos2d-java but it lacks proper documentation etc. And **if you are good in developing c++ or Lua** then you should have a look at [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) for cross platform development. Here is the link for different [2d-game Engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/android/2d_game_engines) including there game samples and other details.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Until now, i never knew how to accept answers. Thanks for your help! :)